# Programmatic mapping with embedded index in Hibernate Search results in unable to find field error

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search, programmatic-config

I am having to do a programmatic configuration of the fields to be indexed with Hibernate Search.

In the scenario below the use of *indexEmbedded()* is resulting in a "field not found error".

```
@Entity
public class AT {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ARRM_IDE", nullable = false)
    private A arr;

    private Date dateType;

    (and other fields)
}

@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "C_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "S_ARRM_01")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "C_SEQUENCE")
    @Column(name = "IDE_ARR")
    private Long id;
}

SearchMapping mapping = new SearchMapping();
mapping.entity(AT.class).indexed()
        .property("dateType", ElementType.FIELD)
        .field()
        .store(Store.YES)
        .property("arr", ElementType.FIELD)
        .indexEmbedded()
        .entity(A.class).indexed()
        .property("id", ElementType.FIELD).documentId().name("arrId")
        .field()
        .store(Store.YES)
        ;
```

When I create and persist entities (I have integrated Hibernate Search with Elasticsearch), the entities are created and the indexes are created in Elasticsearch also.

contents on Elasticsearch:

```
      "_index" : "com.....at",
      "_type" : "com.....AT",
      "_id" : "7744",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "dateType" : "2016-06-12T06:08:52.780Z",
        "arr" : {
          "id" : 6352
        }
      }
    } ]
```

But when I try querying using the Hibernate Search Lucene query it fails:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
        org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
        .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(AT.class).get();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb.bool()
        .must(qb
                .range()
                .onField("dateType")
                .from(parseDate(startDate))
                .to(parseDate(endDate)).excludeLimit()
                .createQuery())
        .must(qb
        .keyword()
        .onField("arr")
        .matching(crsArrId).createQuery())
        .createQuery();
Sort sort = null;
if (order == OrderEnum.ASCENDING) {
    sort = new Sort(
            new SortField("dateType", SortField.Type.STRING));
} else {
    sort = new Sort(
            new SortField("dateType", SortField.Type.STRING, true));
}
FullTextQuery jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, AT.class);
jpaQuery.setSort(sort);
jpaQuery.setFirstResult(offset);
jpaQuery.setMaxResults(maxReturnedEvents);

return jpaQuery.getResultList();
```

Error is:

```
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: Unable to find field arr in com....AT
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.objectToString(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:977)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.FieldContext.objectToString(FieldContext.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.buildSearchTerm(ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.createQuery(ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.createQuery(ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.java:67)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to search on arr.id, not arr.

Just change .onField("arr") to .onField("arr.id").

Comment: It didnt help :( ..it throws a NPE now

Comment: Could you be more specific and provide the stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks Guillaume - I am not sure how but it is working now.